# unique constraint violated (ORA-00001) in concurrent insert

Tags: oracle-11g, primary-key, transaction, concurrency

I have a procedure that is called from concurrent transactions:

```
//Some actions here

INSERT INTO table1
                (table1_id, table1_val1, table1_val2, table1_val3)
              VALUES
                (gettablenewid('TABLE1'), val1, val2, val3);

INSERT INTO table1
                (table1_id, table1_val1, table1_val2, table1_val3)
              VALUES
                (gettablenewid('TABLE1'), val1, val2, val3);
INSERT INTO table1
                (table1_id, table1_val1, table1_val2, table1_val3)
              VALUES
                (gettablenewid('TABLE1'), val1, val2, val3);
//some other actions
```

Function gettablenewid code (id_table stores PKs for each table):

```
create or replace
    function        GetTableNewId(tablename in varchar2)
      return number is
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      Result number;
    cursor c1 is SELECT ig.id_value+1 id_new
                              FROM id_table ig
                              WHERE ig.table_identifier = tablename
                              FOR UPDATE of  ig.id_value;
    begin
    for c1_rec in c1 loop  
      UPDATE id_table ig
         SET ig.id_value = c1_rec.id_new
       WHERE current of c1 ;
       Result:=c1_rec.id_new;
    end loop;
    commit;
      return(Result);
    end GetTableNewId;
```

Occasionally insert statement fails with ORA-00001 for table1_id, I can't undestand why it happens.

Comment: Use sequences!!

Comment: Could it be that somewhere there is an insert without the `GetTableNewId` function or with the wrong tablename ? i.e. you're updating table1 with `gettablenewid('TABLE2')`

Comment: glad [you found a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377620/unique-constraint-violated-ora-00001-in-concurrent-insert): I'm going to close this as it isn't likely to be of help to someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

@A.B.Cade you're right! I found another process that modified id_table concurrently for table_identifier = 'TABLE1'. Thanks to all for your help.